# ng-selected Выборка из массива

Tags: html, angularjs

Помогите использовать функцию выборки объекта из массива для создания нового массива

```
<label for="docPage">Doctor: </label>
<select name="docPage" ng-model="group.doctor">
    <option ng-selected="PickDoctor(doctor)"
            ng-repeat="doctor in doctors"
            value="{{doctor.name}}">
            {{doctor.name}}
    </option> 
</select>
```

Сама функция:

```
self.PickDoctor=function(pDoctor)
{
    doctor=pDoctor;
    console.log(doctor);
}
```

И кнопка на которую привязана функция создания группы:

```
                self.CreateGroup = function() {
                var group = new GroupClass(self.group.name, self.group.code, self.group.doctor,self.group.patient,self.group.usluga);
                group.doctor=doctor;
                group.patient=patient;
                group.usluga=usluga;
                groups.push(group);
```

Comment: для создания нового массива чего?

Answer (score 0):

Суть такова: я трех селектах я выбираю пациента, доктора и услугу для создания приема(массив содержит в себе объекты других массивов). Проблема в том что при таком коде у меня ng-selected="Pick" после ng-repeat выбирает самый последний объект из списка.

Comment: ng-selected нужен для назначения значения атрибута selected, а не для "выбора" чего бы то ни было